# NamedQuery miss places table in OnetoOne relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

i have a problem with named query in my project. I have 2 entities with OneToOne relation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_BRANCH_PARAMS")
public class BranchParams implements Identifiable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SL_BRANCH_PARAM_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SL_BRANCH_PARAM_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "SL_BRANCH_PARAM_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "INTEREST_ACCOUNT_ID")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private AccountDef interestAccount;
}
```

and second class with named query

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_ACCOUNT_DEF")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AccountDef.getAvaibleInterestAccountsForBranch",
            query = "SELECT ad FROM AccountDef ad LEFT JOIN FETCH ad.branchParamsInterest WHERE     ad.branchParamsInterest = NULL ORDER BY ad.id ASC"),
})
public class AccountDef implements Identifiable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SL_ACCOUNT_DEF_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SL_ACCOUNT_DEF_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "SL_ACCOUNT_DEF_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "interestAccount")
    private BranchParams branchParamsInterest;
}
```

When i execute the named query I get this query to database

```
select
    accountdef0_.ID as ID1_10_0_,
    branchpara1_.ID as ID1_13_1_,
    branchpara1_.INTEREST_ACCOUNT_ID as INTERES16_13_1_
from
    SL_ACCOUNT_DEF accountdef0_ 
left outer join
    SL_BRANCH_PARAMS branchpara1_ 
        on accountdef0_.ID=branchpara1_.INTEREST_ACCOUNT_ID 
where
    accountdef0_.ID is null //this is incorrect
order by
    accountdef0_.ID ASC
```

which is not correct because it gives me no rows as it checks if the ID in AccountDef is null instead in BranchParams.

The correct query should look like this

```
select
    accountdef0_.ID as ID1_10_0_,
    branchpara1_.ID as ID1_13_1_,
    branchpara1_.INTEREST_ACCOUNT_ID as INTERES16_13_1_
from
    SL_ACCOUNT_DEF accountdef0_ 
left outer join
    SL_BRANCH_PARAMS branchpara1_ 
        on accountdef0_.ID=branchpara1_.INTEREST_ACCOUNT_ID 
where
    branchpara1_.ID is null //this is correct
order by
    accountdef0_.ID ASC
```

and such query returns the rows i want. And the question from me is, why named query checks null id value for AccountDef instead for BranchParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "AccountDef.getAvaibleInterestAccountsForBranch",
        query = "SELECT ad FROM AccountDef ad LEFT JOIN FETCH ad.branchParamsInterest bp WHERE bp.interestAccount = NULL ORDER BY ad.id ASC")
```

Comment: Thank you very much jimfromsa, I changed it to bp.id and it works like charm!